# Spring Boot - Shell commands interrupted by logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shell

The question is quite self explanatory, but I will elaborate here.

TL;DR - Is there a way to prevent system prints and logging from interrupting the writing of shell commands in Spring boot

I am developing a small Spring boot application and am adding some shell commands to make the user experience a bit better. However whenever a user connects to one of the API end points I want to log their activity. The issue is that this interrupts the writing of shell commands and only what remains on the last line is taken as part of the command. I can understand the logic behind this, but is there a way to circumvent that? From what I have found out using a simple system in doesn't get interrupted by the logging

Comment: Are you talking about Spring Shell, or does shell commands mean commands executed via Process and ProcessBuilder? Also, how is your logging configured? I assume you are using logback (or log4j) and directing the logging to a file?

Comment: I am talking about Spring Shell, sorry for not clarifying. And I am logging to console for the most significant of messages (like USER issued admin help)